# Center the Button Text Content in a universal app

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I am trying to center the text Content of a Button in Center,in my universal app,but this is what I get:

[image]

and this is my code:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"  >
                        <Border  VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="40"  >
                            <Button  Background="Transparent" Content="Resultats" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="#727271"  x:Name="res" Style="{Binding Source={StaticResource ButtontopStyle}}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Click="res_Click" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Height="40"/>
                        </Border>
                        <StackPanel x:Name="stackVisible" Orientation="Vertical" >
                        <Border Margin="0" >
                                <Button  Background="Transparent" Content="Tous les résultats" FontSize="14" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#727271" Margin="0"  x:Name="ttres" Style="{Binding Source={StaticResource ButtonMenuStyle}}"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Padding="10" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Height="40"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Border>
                                <Button Background="Transparent" Content="Recherches Avancées" FontSize="14" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#727271" Margin="0"  x:Name="rechavan"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{Binding Source={StaticResource ButtonMenuStyle}}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Padding="10" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Height="40"/>
                        </Border>
                        </StackPanel>
          </StackPanel>
```

I tried to use VerticalContentAlignment="Center",but like you see,I didn't get the result that I want
thanks for help

my styles for buttons:

```
<Style  x:Key="ButtonMenuStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#e6e6e6"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#e6e6e6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#e6e6e6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border" />
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#e6e6e6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Content" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Grid>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="Border" Stroke="Transparent" Fill="Transparent" Margin="0"/>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style  x:Key="ButtontopStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#e6e6e6"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#e6e6e6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Button" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#e6e6e6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Button" />
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#e6e6e6" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Content" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Grid>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="Button" Stroke="Transparent" Fill="Transparent" Margin="0"/>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: We can't see all the code... what's in your ButtontopStyle ? When I try your snippet it just works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're putting too much effort into it, and most likely the `ButtonMenuStyle` has something that messes up your layout. By default the content of a `Button` is vertically centered.

I've thrown out all your unnecessary alignments, unnecessary borders (and you could even remove the inner `StackPanel` as well). I've also changed the font size to 8 on one button to show multiple sizes to prove they're all aligned correctly.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <Button Background="Transparent" Content="Resultats" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="#727271" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Height="40"/>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
        <Button Background="Transparent" Content="Tous les résultats" FontSize="14" Foreground="#727271" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Height="40"/>
        <Button Background="Transparent" Content="Recherches Avancées" FontSize="8" Foreground="#727271" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Height="40" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

[image]

---

Edit: as you posted your styles, I looked into them. I'd strongly advise against using them (as they break several things), but if you really want to use them, you should change your `ContentPresenter` too:

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
```

If you want to modify the button control template, look at default template in following file (line 2147) for a starting point:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.10240.0\Generic\generic.xaml

Comment: Good points, Bart.  For those that don't want to dig through the generic.xaml, you can browse by control in msdn as well... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299122.aspx